# Getting 400 Bad Request with Grails Spring Security Rest Plugin

Tags: spring, rest, grails

I'm trying grails restful spring security rest plugin.
I'm using Grails 2.5.2 with spring-security-rest:1.5.2. 
I'm unable to make login work with the following ajax call. I get 400 bad request. But if I try to use CURL command it works! I don't understand what's wrong.

That's the ajax post call:

```
var config = {
            type : 'POST'
            ,url : '/api/login'
            ,data : {username:"xxxx",password:"xxxx"}
            ,async : false
            ,dataType : 'JSON'
            ,contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
            ,success: function(response) {
                console.dir(response);
            }
            ,error : function (response) {
                console.dir(response);
            }
        }

        $.ajax(config);
```

Spring rest plugin configuration inside Config.groovy is:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',  // Stateless chain
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                                                          // Traditional chain
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.active=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.failureStatusCode=401
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.active=true
```

This is my curl command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"xxxxx", "password":"xxxx"}' http://localhost:8080/api/login
```

and that's the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 2172
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 13:28:42 GMT

{"username":"xxxxxx","roles":["ROLE_ADMIN"],"token_type":"Bearer","access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NTY4NDI1MjIsInN1YiI6ImFkbWluZGllIiwicHJpbmNpcGFsIjoiSDRzSUFBQUFBQUFBQUpWU3YwOFVRUlIrZXg2QlNLSmdnb2tGTm1KbjloTG92RWJBMDJDV3czQmNnNGxrYnZleERqYzdzODdNSG5jTnVVb0xDZ2hJWXVLXC93SDhpalgrQWdZS1cydFkzeThFZU5JU3BkdDk4Kzczdnh4NWZ3SWpSTUJkcnhvWHhVNUhGWFBvbTFWekdCc05NYzl2ek00TTZRcHNqM3VmQUprM2c4bmdsOEFJbzhjakNrMkNMZFZoRk1CbFhWbHBiR05wcVY4T3MwdkdBY1ZPekJMZVZidnZYM0tIU2VHTkJRZTI5S2NIb09reXlNRlNadEhVb................... etc.etc.
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to open debugger in your browser and check what exactly are you sending to server? If you debug the request you would check the difference betweeen it and the working curl version and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on [official docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you should change dataType to 'json':

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))

btw did you try to remove `async : false` from config and check it?

Comment: Hi Michal, thank you for your answer. I just found solution. I have to post data with JSON.stringify function...that's was the problem! My fault of course.